# Create tiled map with no geo location using flutter_map package

Tags: flutter, dart, leaflet, fluttermap

I'd like to tile a large image and view it in a Flutter app with flutter_map package. I.e, use the flutter_map package as a large bitmap viewer for a zoomable, tiled image.

On the web I can achieve this with Leaflet and believe it's quite a common use case?

In Leaflet I can tile an image and create a map as follows. Assuming an image size of 7680x4320 which gets tiled with zoom levels 0 (512x512) through to level 4 (full image resolution).

```
 var mapExtent = [0.00000000, -4320.00000000, 7680.00000000, 0.00000000];
  var mapMinZoom = 0;
  var mapMaxZoom = 4;
  var mapMaxResolution = 1.00000000;
  var mapMinResolution = Math.pow(2, mapMaxZoom) * mapMaxResolution;
  var tileExtent = [0.00000000, -4320.00000000, 7680.00000000, 0.00000000];
  var crs = L.CRS.Simple;
  crs.transformation = new L.Transformation(1, -tileExtent[0], -1, tileExtent[3]);
  crs.scale = function(zoom) {
    return Math.pow(2, zoom) / mapMinResolution;
  };
  crs.zoom = function(scale) {
    return Math.log(scale * mapMinResolution) / Math.LN2;
  };
  var layer;
  var map = new L.Map('map', {
      maxZoom: mapMaxZoom,
      minZoom: mapMinZoom,
      crs: crs
    });
    
    layer = L.tileLayer('{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      minZoom: mapMinZoom, maxZoom: mapMaxZoom,
      tileSize: L.point(512, 512),
      noWrap: true,
      tms: false
    }).addTo(map);
  map.fitBounds([
    crs.unproject(L.point(mapExtent[2], mapExtent[3])),
    crs.unproject(L.point(mapExtent[0], mapExtent[1]))
  ]);
```

Is there a way or example to use flutter_map and CrsSimple to achieve the same thing in Dart?

Thanks,